# What is the name for this technique to prepare eggs?

Tags: eggs

I prefer to make my eggs similar *sunny side up*, but I flip them and cook them on both sides. I don't use oil, so they're not *fried* either.

I crack them into a pre-heated pan at medium high heat, wait until the yolk solidifies a bit, and then flip them and wait a little bit less time. The yolk usually has a film over it, and often comes out somewhere between runny and solid, depending on how long I leave it.

Comment: Frying without oil is still frying.

Comment: Indeed - and since the eggs have oil in them, you are frying them, just without *additional* oil.

Comment: sounds like over easy isn't quite it. you accepted and answer an hour after asking. I would suggest that you wait a while and compare answers before accepting.

Comment: over easy the yolk would not be set, or barely, barely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That would be cooking eggs "*over easy*"

https://www.google.com/search?q=eggs%20over%20easy

Comment: And is there a different word for it when the yolks are completely set up?

Comment: "Over well" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_egg

Comment: Or "Over hard".

Comment: @WayfaringStranger- That's what I thought as well but the Wikipedia article said that over hard is when the yolks are popped and is the same thing as "fried"

Comment: @Sobachatina They're all fried. The point of over hard is that the yolk is totally cooked, just like a hard boiled egg.

Comment: I did short order eggs for a while, in Iowa and Alaska. To me "over hard" means the egg is fried on one side, then the yolk is broken, then it is flipped and fried on the other side. Over well is the same, but the yolk isn't broken, it's just cooked long enough to solidify the yolk.

Comment: @Random832- of course they are all fried but if you order an egg "fried" you will get an egg with a broken yolk, cooked solid.

Answer (score 8):

I'd actually call those "over medium" or "over hard", not over easy. A perfect egg over easy would have all of the egg white totally cooked and solidified, but the yolk should be almost totally runny. Over medium would be a half-solid, half-runny yolk (more or less), and over hard ("over well" works too I guess, I've never heard that but maybe one of the two is a regional term) would mean the yolk is totally cooked through and solid.

Comment: If it's a properly done 'over medium' egg, the yolk is thickened ... between solid and runny, not exactly 'half-solid'.  But yes, that's what was described.

Comment: @Joe "half-solid, half-runny" could mean either that half of the yolk is solid and half runny, or that the yolk is half-way between solid and runny (i.e., viscous).

Comment: The question said "somewhere between runny and solid" meaning that they are running the entire range from easy to hard- not that his eggs were always in the middle of the range. In my experience, "over easy" is a far more common term than "over medium". Many people have never heard "over medium" or "over hard" at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have used the term 'sunny side down' to describe these.

This article uses that term http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Sunny-Side-Down-Eggs

And a Google search returns pages/images that match your description.